# Saving JSON File with Many Nested Objects to a List

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I currently have a JSON file that has the following format. Keep in mind that this is not the entire file. The entire JSON file is comprised of hundreds of lists of key, value pairs that follow one after another between square brackets [][][]...etc. I am trying to store each of these individual lists e.g. the list below in a structure so that I may iterate the structure and parse each list for filename, labels etc. I initially tried to import this using json.loads() but I am having issues due the nested nature of the objects. I would appreciate any ideas/insight on how I can go about importing this file into a list or other appropriate python structure.

```
[
   {
      "File_Name": "1.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Flora"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Grass"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 94.77251434326172,
               "Name": "Plant"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Animal"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Cheetah"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Mammal"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 78.49254608154297,
               "Name": "Wildlife"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Field"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Grassland"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 69.79740142822266,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 67.31356048583984,
               "Name": "Leisure Activities"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 67.31356048583984,
               "Name": "Walking"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Jaguar"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Leopard"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 57.44683837890625,
               "Name": "Panther"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 55.88261032104492,
               "Name": "Bush"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 55.88261032104492,
               "Name": "Vegetation"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 53.4413948059082,
               "Name": "Lawn"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "978e32e4-1da8-11e8-a380-cd680f89684e",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "978e32e4-1da8-11e8-a380-cd680f89684e",
               "content-length": "947",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   }
][
   {
      "File_Name": "2.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Astronomy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Galaxy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Nebula"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Night"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outer Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Universe"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
               "content-length": "449",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   },
   {
      "File_Name": "2.jpg",
      "Analysis": {
         "Labels": [
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Astronomy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Galaxy"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Nebula"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Night"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Outer Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Space"
            },
            {
               "Confidence": 98.57389068603516,
               "Name": "Universe"
            }
         ],
         "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RetryAttempts": 0,
            "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
            "RequestId": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
            "HTTPHeaders": {
               "date": "Thu, 01 Mar 2018 23:30:59 GMT",
               "x-amzn-requestid": "98d2c109-1da8-11e8-a2d9-b91cf22c7f33",
               "content-length": "449",
               "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
               "connection": "keep-alive"
            }
         },
         "OrientationCorrection": "ROTATE_0"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you give a better idea of the structure? I need to know which key you need and what the list should look like at the end. Also are there many of the file results? Is it the labels list you want?

Comment: @cal97g yes I will have to collect the file name, all labels and confidence values. I shouldn't have any problem parsing the individual JSON objects, I just have never dealt with/imported such a large nested JSON file before in Python.

Comment: The problem is not really clear. Could you provide what the expected result looks like? Also, it'd be useful if you provide the code of the attempt you made as to have a better idea of what you're after

Comment: @damores basically the issue is I want to import a JSON file into my python script. Say I use the best answer provided by cal97g (top big_json_file snippet) I will receive a ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded because of the format of the JSON file

Answer (score 1):

```
big_json_file = json.loads(file_string)
big_list_of_labels = []

for file in big_json_file:
    big_list_of_labels.append(file['Analysis']['Labels'])
```

Or if you want to store the file name and the list I'd recommend something like:

```
my_processed_dict = {}
for file in big_json_file:
    my_processed_dict[file['File_Name']] = file['Analysis']['Labels']
```

where you can iterate over my_processed_dict with:

```
for key, value in my_processed_dict.items():
    # value is the list of confidence values!
    pass
```